# Spring @RequestBody annotation in Restful web service

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, spring-mvc

Thanks to `@RestController` I don't need to add annotation `@ResposneBody`, cause spring knows that it is rest controller, and he will not generate view, but instead it will return `json` object.

Unfortunately there is one more annotation related to this topic. It is `@RequestBody`, when controller method accept `json` object as a parameter. And it will have to be pointed before that parameter.

My question is there a way to get rid of that annotation (`@RequestBody`).? If my controller is rest controller (`@RestController` instead of regular `@Controller`) it should be demanded from spring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you'll have to specify `@RequestBody`. A Java method can have only a single return value, and so the `@ResponseBody` is unambiguous, but there are multiple possible ways that mapped controller parameters might be interpreted (in particular, using `@ModelAttribute` with form encoding is a very common alternative to `@RequestBody` with JSON), and you'll need to tell Spring how to map the incoming request.

Comment: `@ModelAttribute` is no more an alternative to `@RequestBody` than an apple is to an orange.

Comment: @zeroflagL Which is to say, a bit different but often a plausible substitute.

Comment: You can omit any annotation when a request contains form encoded data. The point of `@ModelAttribute` is to add something to the model (sic!), i.e. make it available for a view.